# passing while() array to a variable out of while() in php

Tags: php, arrays, loops

suppose i have a query

```
$array = array();
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
 $data = $row['data'];
}
$array = $data;
```

Now how can i get that each $data values out of while in an array() i.e $array

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$array = array();
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $array[] = $row['data'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

by adding each $row to array $data
for reference: http://php.net/types.array

Note that there is no such a thing as "while() array". There are just arrays only.

Answer (score 1):

Your $data variable is being overwritten during each iteration. So you need to turn it into `$data[]` and $data should be declared at the top, or you can just use $array[] as the other answer suggests, not sure why you put in the $data variable in their in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You need to save each iteration object into a "new" object, so your code will look just like:

```
$array = array();
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
   $array[] = $row['data'];
}
```

please note the line:

```
   $array[] = $row['data'];
```

### References:

- [PHP Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array();
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
   $array[] = $row['data'];
}
```

further u can use

```
$array['data']
```

and u can also use `mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)` instead `mysql_fetch_array($sql)`